# Laravel: Update value of a column on button click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello i'm still new to laravel and I've searching the web for almost 3 hours about this issue I have I tried many things but it didn't work.

So basicly I have a page with a button , when I click that button "Approve" I want to update the value from 0 to 1 (the column is of type boolean). 
This is my controller :

```
public function approve($id){
    $training = Training::find($id);
    $training->update(['Approved' =>'1']);


    // $training->Approved = 1;
   // $training->save();
    return redirect('/trainings')->with('success', 'Training Approved');
}
```

This is page section with the button it's in the folder trainings and has the name " show.blade.php" :

```
 {!!Form::open(['action' => ['TrainingsController@approve',$training->TrainingsID], 'method' => 'POST','class' => 'pull-left'])!!}
            {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
            {{Form::submit('Approve',['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}

    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

and the routes (I guess this is the part I'm doing wrong):

```
Route::post('/trainings',['as' =>'trainings.show', 'uses' => 'TrainingsController@approve']);
```

The error I get when clicking the button is this :

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 1):

Since the route is `post`, you should change form method to post too:

```
{{ Form::hidden('_method','POST') }}
```

Or:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'action' => ....
```

You also need to add `id` to the route definition:

```
Route::post('trainings/{id}', ['as' => 'trainings.show', 'uses' => 'TrainingsController@approve']);
```

Comment: Indeed you're right but now I get this error: Type error:" Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TrainingsController::approve(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected" but I'm giving the TrainingsID right? So I dont understand

Comment: @AbdelKdj please read the second part of my answer. Have you changed the route? Also, you're redirecting to `return redirect('/trainings')`, so you need to have another route for it, or you want to pass the ID too like `return redirect('trainings/' . $id)`

Comment: sorry I didn't see it, okay now it triggers the error validations messages of my update method in the controller ,i'm kinda confused now and also it doesn't update the table :/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need method spoofing here, since you using a `POST` action. Its only necessary for `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`.

Your current route definition is wrong because you connect `trainings/show` with the `approve` action. In fact it should be a `show` action.

This is the code which should work (untested)

```
class TrainingsController extends Controller 
{
    public function show(Training $training) // Using Route Model binding here 
    {
         return view('trainings.show', ['training' => $training]);
    }

    public function approve(Training $training) 
    {
        $training->update(['Approved' => '1']);

        return redirect()->route('trainings')->with('success', 'Training Approved'); // if you want to redirect to a list of all trainings and would need an index action
        // return redirect()->route('trainings', ['training' => $training])->with('success', 'Training Approved'); // if you want redirect to detail page of this training
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('trainings/{training}/approve', ['as' => 'trainings.approve', 'uses' => 'TrainingsController@approve']); 
Route::get('trainings/{training}', ['as' => 'trainings.show', 'uses' => 'TrainingsController@show']);
```

Blade

```
{!!Form::open('route' => ['trainings.approve', $training->TrainingsID], 'class' => 'pull-left'])!!}
    {{Form::submit('Approve',['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Some remarks on your code:

- an ID like `TrainingsID` is redundant because you already know that is the ID of training
- stick to `snake_case` table / attribute names for your model/db fields